# Equation of normal to an ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

> Show that the equation of the normal at the point $x = a\cos(t)$, $y = b\sin(t)$ of the 
>   ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1  $$
>   is $$\frac{2a^2 - b^2}{a}$$

Hi, I am not sure how to proceed on this question, i have got as far as:

$$x\ a\ \sin(t) - y\ b\ \cos(t) = (a^2 - b^2)\sin(t)\cos(t)$$

By using $y - y1 = m(x - x1)$ and the gradient from the derivative of the ellipse equation. Please can you help

Comment: Something is missing in the statement of the problem, because the expression $$\frac{2a^2-b^2}{a}$$ is not an equation, let alone an equation for a line.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the normal of the region $F(x,y) = C$ at the point $(x_0, y_0)$
has direction $\nabla F(x_0, y_0)$.

Here $F(x,y) = x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2$, hence the direction is
$
(x_0/a^2, y_0/b^2)
$ and the complete parametric equation is
$$
M(t) = (x_0 + x_0/a^2 t, y_0 + y_0/b^2 t)
$$
or, in implicit form (just get rid of $t$):
$$
y/y_0 - 1 = \frac{a^2}{b^2} (x/x_0 - 1) 
$$